# Out files are marked red in intellij after importing a project from github and executing main without errors

Tags: github, intellij-idea

Hello I am new to Intellij.

When I run main it executes without errors and creates an "out" folder which contains the same classes from my src but they are marked red. My classes dont have any errors but the program doesnt do what its supposed to. How do I fix the classes in out being marked red?

Answer (score 0):

ok fixed by adding to gitignore. everything works